# Can't input number zero (0) in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From this code, why can't I input the number 0. So I want when I input a number in front of or behind a 0, the value will be replaced by the number entered, but after that I can input another 0 behind it because it is for calculations. For example, if I input 10, then only the number 1 is entered, the number 0 is not entered

```
const numberToString = (text) => {
        text = text.toString().replace(/,/g, '');
        let number = parseFloat(Math.round(text * 100) / 100);

        let decimals = number % 1 === 0 ? 0 : 2;
        number = number.toFixed(decimals);

        let parts = number.toString().split(".");
        parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        return parts.join(".");
    };


 const onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let text = e.target.value;
         text = text.toString().replace(/,/g, '');
        text = text.replace(/^0+|0+$/g, '');
        text = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        var number = parseFloat(Math.round(text * 100) / 100);
        let details = calculatorDetails;
        if (!isNaN(number)) {
            if (e.target.name === "kursIDR") {
                setFormData({
                    ...formData,
                    [e.target.name]: number,
                    ["v" + e.target.name]: text,
                });
            }
 else {
            setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
        }
    };

 <div className="row align-items-center mb-3">
                                    <label className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Electrical Testing & COMM</label>
                                    <div className="col-sm-10">
                                        <input name="electricalTestingComm" value={velectricalTestingComm} type="text" className="form-control text-right" onChange={isCountReverse ? (e) => onCountReverseChange(e) : (e) => onChange(e)} readOnly={status === 'Submitted' || status === 'User Approved' || status === 'Customer Approved' || status === 'Failed' || status === 'Canceled'} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: In your onChange function, the second regex replace is mangling your number, see `console.log('10'.replace(/^0+|0+$/g, ''));` (output: `1`)

Comment: do you have a solution regarding this?

Comment: don't remove trailing zeros - also, don't remove leading zeros if the value is `"0"` though, if `0` is an invalid value you can

Comment: So initially the input value is 0, but I want to input 0 either in front or behind it to immediately replace it with the number that was input, but after that you can input 0 again, for example 1000, 2200 and so on.

Comment: yeah, so don't remove trailing zeros

Comment: how to do that? @JaromandaX

Comment: fix the regex as per James first comment an hour ago

Comment: Is the number of decimal places really dependent on the number being even or odd?

Comment: Could you edit with 5 user entered numbers and what the `numberToString` should output for each? - Because to me... that simply is unclear as a whole and tempted to mark as "Need details or clarity".